# Windows batch - ftp uploading and connection

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I would like to upload a file to my ftp server if internet is connected

In each run, i prefer:

```
if (ftp server can be connected){
   upload the file "C:\abc.txt" to the ftp server directory "/ABC_DB"
}
```

Thus, I am not sure how to check ftp connection, is it possible to run like this:

```
echo abc > C:\abc.txt
???Check the connection here 
OPEN your.ftp.server.com
usernameabc
passwordbcd
CD /ABC_DB
PUT "C:\abc.txt"
QUIT
PAUSE
```

Sorry for asking such silly question, but I am new in batch, hope u can help me =[

Comment: `ping your.ftp.server.com` <-- does that command get any replies?

Comment: yes. 
since I am going to run the script maybe twice a day, I prefer it upload the file to the ftp server if it can connect to ftp server otherwise it show error message to a log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this: change lines 2,3,4 with your details

```
@echo off
set "name=your_ftp_user-name"
set "password=your_ftp_password"
set "server=ftp_server_name"

ping %server% |find /i "TTL=" >nul || (echo server offline, aborting&pause&goto :EOF)

set "ftpScript=%temp%\%~nx0.ftp.tmp"
(
    echo open %server%
    echo %name%
    echo %password%
    echo bin
    echo CD /ABC_DB
    echo PUT "C:\abc.txt"
    echo quit
) > "%ftpScript%"

ftp -i -s:"%ftpScript%"
del     "%ftpScript%"
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me


ftp> open x.x.x.x
Connected to x.x.x.x.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (x.x.x.x:(none)):
331 Password required for I_PUT_User_Name_Here.

530 User cannot log in.
Login failed.
ftp> CD /DeviceReport
530 Please login with USER and PASS.

Any comment for it ><

Comment: Note that I login successful when I use cmd but not batch

Comment: And you can read my original post show above, I just edit something for you =]

Comment: Your authentication details are wrong - possibly a space where there shouldn't be one, or a typo.

Comment: Note that your previous code is right. I got error because some wrong configure in my ftp server lol. Again, Many thanks ^^